# Excel Data - Needs to be in separate rows

Tags: excel, formatting

I have a bunch of data, but I need it to be formatted into columns so that "1" will be in column A, "G:" will be in column B, and so on... Right now everything is in column "A"

[image]

Comment: "Text to Columns " function should be able to achieve your requirement

Answer (score 1):

Good that you found a way to do this task. There is another way to do this with a formula,

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,",",REPT(" ",999)),1+((COLUMN(A1)-1)*999),999))
```

Just enter this formula and drag it right and then down.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out using **Data>Text to Columns** and the delimiter option. Thanks!